# Automating Greenshot using QTP

Tags: screenshot

I was looking for a way to automate greenshot using QTP via the VB rather than recording the entire process but was not able to find a good starting point for the same. Anyone who has tried this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an open General Feature Request for a Greenshot API with COM interface. Refer [this link](http://sourceforge.net/p/greenshot/feature-requests/411/) for updates.